# arctan of a square root as a rational multiple of pi

Tags: nt.number-theory

I know that if $x$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, then $tan(x)$ is [algebraic](http://divisbyzero.com/2010/10/28/trigonometric-functions-and-rational-multiples-of-pi/).

Is there a fairly simple way to express $x$ as $\pi\ m/n$, if $tan(x)$ is given as a square root of a rational?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An angle $x$ with $\tan^2 x$ rational has been called "geodetic" by Conway, Radin, and Sadun, [On Angles Whose Squared Trigonometric Functions are Rational](http://arxiv.org/abs/math--ph/9812019). Geodetic angles have a simple representation, see their Theorem 2, but they are not in general rational multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $tan^2(x\pi) \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $tan(x\pi) \in \{0, \pm\sqrt{3}, \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \pm 1 \}$.

Chapter 11 of the *[A Concrete Approach to Abstract Algebra](http://books.google.com/books?id=emE6SLT3CLsC&dq=Angles+Whose+Squared+Trigonometric+Functions+Are+Rational&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* has a simple proof of this fact.

Also, a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79861/arctan2-a-rational-multiple-of-pi) has proofs that can be extended to this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can numerically compute $\arctan(\tan(x))=\pi \frac{m}{n}$. Then divide by $\pi$ and numerically search for linear relation between $(K,1)$ to recover $m,n$. I am not sure there is always a solution.